# C# TCP server for connecting GPS devices

Tags: c#

I want to develop a TCP server which will accept around 5000 GPS client connection Currently I have developed a simple multi threaded TCP server which is unable handle even 100 clients. It consumes around 98% of CPU. What may be the problem and what is the best approach for this purpose?

Comment: We can't possibly debug that problem unless you tell us a lot more about your application.

Comment: Multithreading is almost certainly the wrong answer for solving the [c10k problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html).

Comment: You could run a CPU profiler and see where the application is spending most of this 98% CPU time.

Comment: In my program I am using TCP Listener to accept client connections(one thread per connection). First device sends its unique id. After that server sends response. After getting the correct response, device sends the gps data, which server has to parse and put it in database. What is the best mechanism I can use for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the asynchronous socket APIs. One thread per connection does not scale.

This will require rewriting significant amounts of the existing code to be asynchronous.

Comment: I have tried with asynchronous socket APIs. But the problem is same. It consumes lot of cpu. Can you tell me the possible reasons?

Comment: It's possible that your message processing is CPU bound. You need to use a performance monitoring tool to determine the exact reason.

Comment: I used dot trace for monitoring cpu usage and found that Network.Read() is taking more time in synchronous mechanism. So, I introduced Thread.sleep before that. Now it is not taking much cpu, But as the time passes, the number of active threads is increasing. I tried to forcefully close threads using Abort(). But its making no diffrence

Comment: There's a lot wrong with that. Why is `Read` being called so often? Are you not properly handling a zero return from `Read`? `Sleep` should never be necessary, and `Abort` should absolutely never be used.